# When using Sheets API to delete multiple rows and the endIndex is a row that doesn't exist in the sheet, how to handle it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When pushing the rows to be deleted into an array, the last `endIndex` whose value is `809` is a row that is not in the sheet. How can I handle it in this case?

This is the piece of code building the request:

```
const sheetId = fabricDbSht.getSheetId();
let requests = [];
const fabricDbValues = fabricDbSht.getRange(1, 1, fabricDbSht.getLastRow(), fabricDbSht.getLastColumn()).getValues();
for (let a = fabricDbValues.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
  if (fabricDbValues[a][0] == systemId) {
    let row = a + 1;
    if (row > 0) {
      requests.push({
        deleteDimension: {
          range: {
            sheetId,
            startIndex: row,
            endIndex: row + 1,
            dimension: "ROWS"
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
console.log('Requests: ' + JSON.stringify(requests))
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests}, fileId);
```

This is what the `requests` array looks like:

```
Requests: [{
  "deleteDimension": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 2032612900,
      "startIndex": 808,
      "endIndex": 809,
      "dimension": "ROWS"
    }
  }
}, {
  "deleteDimension": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 2032612900,
      "startIndex": 807,
      "endIndex": 808,
      "dimension": "ROWS"
    }
  }
}, {
  "deleteDimension": {
    "range": {
      "sheetId": 2032612900,
      "startIndex": 806,
      "endIndex": 807,
      "dimension": "ROWS"
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About `When pushing the rows to be deleted into an array, the last endIndex whose value is 809 is a row that is not in the sheet. How can I handle it in this case?`, how about removing the 1st element of your requests? Or, how about creating the request body by checking the maximum number of rows with a script? But, I'm not sure about your actual expected result. So, can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result?

Comment: The goal is to have it delete specific rows as efficiently as possible. When running `Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests}, fileId);` , I get: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[1].deleteDimension: Cannot delete a row that doesn't exist. Tried to delete row index 809 but there are only 808 rows`, @Tanaike! Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have already 2 suggestions in my comment. If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I guess my question in this case would be how can I have the `startIndex` and the `endIndex` when the `endIndex` is not an existing row, @Tanaike? I've added the piece building the requests.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. From your script, I proposed a modification point. Please confirm it. But, I cannot still understand your actual expected result. So, when this modification point was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, I'm worried that you might misunderstand `startIndex` and `endIndex`. In this case, the 1st index is `0`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let row = a + 1;
```

#### To:

```
let row = a;
```

Comment: Just getting acquainted with `Sheets API`. Thanks!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.